# Read File (not string) from Websphere MQ and save in to local drive

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am able to connect with MQ and read the message.
But here, the MQ has a file input not a string ( zipped file some kind of .eff extension) and i need to read from MQ and write in to the filesystem directory.

I have done the below code and i could write the string (not sure) in to file named Myfile.eff . But when i am extracting this, it shows error " Cannot Open File "Myfile.eff" as archive". 
I can see the file size is 643KB.

```
public string GetMessageOffQueue()
        {
            string message = "";
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

            try
            {
                queue.Get(queueMessage);
                message = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);

                FileStream fs = new FileStream("Myfile.eff"e, FileMode.Create);
                // Create the writer for data.
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                bw.Write(message);
                fs.Close();
                bw.Close();

                using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter( "Myfile2.eff", true))
                {
                    myStream.Write(message);
                }


            }
            catch (MQException MQExp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MQQueue::Get ended with " + MQExp.Message);
            }
            return message;
        }
```

How can i read and write the exact file in to my directory ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage to read and save in to local directory.
The solution is as below;

MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                mqGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

```
            MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();

            queue.Get(msg, mqGetMsgOpts);
            MQGetMessageOptions mqGetNextMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            mqGetNextMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string messageText = msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength);
                    //Write to File
                    byte[] byteConent = new byte[msg.MessageLength];
                    msg.ReadFully(ref byteConent, 0, msg.MessageLength);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("sample.eff", byteConent);
                    //
                    msg = new MQMessage();
                    queue.Get(msg, mqGetNextMsgOpts);
                }
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                // Handle it
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm

ReadString converts the data into Unicode for you - not what you want

Try using ReadBytes, which gives a byte array